# How to tweak some the javascript in webview in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I am using WebView inside my ReactNative Application.

I want to tweak some of the Javascript of the given/attached URL (inside the webView) of my reactnative application, How to insert my own JS using injectJavaScript or injectedJavaScript. If I only want to change at a specific point like on one action button to capture an image, I want to open the camera of my phone using that button which is embedded inside the webView URL.

Any help?

Comment: Can you provide some code or example codebase you're working with?

Comment: I don't have any code right now, I'm searching for ways, currently the project is in design phase and I have to collect information about this, What I'm trying to do is We have created a web app that I want to use in my react native app and I think we can do that by using webview, but we may want some of the functions that exist in webview to override with one that is defined in app, the reason why I'm trying to do this is that when webview requests camera or file picker it may not work, let me know there's another way to do this
Thank you